# div with anchor

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what is the best practice here. I have a sprite with 2 button images in it. 
I want to set one div to be the first half of the sprite and the other div to be the second half of the sprit. The problem is i'm not sure if the div is the way to go, as I need them both to link to something differently. I read where its bad practice to wrap the div in an a href tag. So how would some go about this.

Comment: Can't you just set the background on the `<a>` tag ?

Comment: Can you please write your code?

Comment: I didn't think you could set the background of an a tag and work in most browsers?

Comment: You are correct that you should never put a div inside an anchor tag.  Anchors are considered terminal elements and, as such, should only contain text and no markup.  Most browsers still render it happily but you can't guarantee consistency across all browsers.  It's better not to do that, plus it won't validate with any kind of css/html validation tool.  Take a look here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: @SRM, @Chapsterj - '_never put a div inside an anchor tag_', unless using HTML5 where it's perfectly valid. Pre-HTML5, inline elements are valid in `<a>` tags, block level elements aren't.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in HTML5 then you can nest a block level element such as a `div` inside an `<a>` tag.

If you're writing HTML4, then you could substitute an inline element such as a `span`. It is valid to nest a `span` inside an anchor in HTML4 or XHTML. To style the `span` as if it were a block level element, you could set its `display` property to `block`.

But as others have suggested already, unless you need the extra element, you can probably just style the anchor element directly. This avoids the necessity to add additional markup purely for stylistic purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the sprite with an anchor then style accordingly.  You should keep in mind an anchor is an inline element, so you would need to set `display:inline-block;`, then go from there.

Comment: Something like this. <div id="leftArrow"><a  href="#"></a></div>. Then in css set the a tag to inline block?

Comment: hmm this worked great but then I went to set the a:hover to move the position of my sprite and realized that the background image was not on the a but the div?

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tags instead of divs.

Set each anchor to the height and width of the sprite like you would the divs. Set the image as a background image. Set display to block. If the image sprite has the text for the link and you don't need HTML text, then make sure to set the text indent to -9999px. (this is better than using pure images because search engines can still read the text).

Comment: no this works currently, no problem, I do it all the time. It's actually the CSS that makes it possible, not the HTML